Does the image of exp of lie algebra generate its lie group?
Let G be a connected Lie group and $\mathfrak{g}$ be its Lie algebra. Let $e_1, \dots, e_n$ be a basis of $\mathfrak{g}$.
Consider standart map $\mathit{exp}: \mathfrak{g} \to G$. It is a diffeomoprhism between neighborhood of 0 of $\mathfrak{g}$ and of identity element e of G.
Is it true that $\mathit{exp}(t_1e_1), \dots, \mathit{exp}(t_ne_n)$, where $t_i$ is small enough, generate a neighborhood of e of G and, therefore, all G?
I cannot be sure because it is not true in general case that
$$\mathit{exp}(a+b)=\mathit{exp}(a)\mathit{exp}(b),$$
and the fact that every element of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a linear combination of $t_1e_1, \dots, t_ne_n$ does not lead to that every element of $G$ is a multiplication of $\mathit{exp}(t_1e_1), \dots, \mathit{exp}(t_ne_n)$.

Your question is unclear: are you allowing to mulitply $\exp(t_1e_1)$ and $\exp(t_2 e_2)$ (for $t_1, t_2$ belonging to a small interval $(-\epsilon, \epsilon)$)? Or maybe you are requiring exactly the same parameter $t$ for all generators? Depending on this, you will get different answers even for Abelian Lie groups.

@MoisheKohan I allow to multiply $exp(t_ie_i)$ with different $t_i$ (because every element of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a linear combination of $t_ie_i$ with different $t_i$), I will correct the question

Then the hint is to compute the derivative of the map $(t_1,...,t_n)\mapsto \exp(t_1e_1)....\exp(t_n e_n)$ at $(0,....,0)$ and use the Inverse Function Theorem.
